# Compactness of automorphic quotient - quaternion group and $\mathrm{GL}_{2}$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, quaternions, algebraic-groups, automorphic-forms

Let $\mathbb{A} = \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ be an adele ring over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $G_{1} = \mathrm{GL}_{2}$, $G_{2} = \mathrm{Res}_{D/\mathbb{Q}}\mathrm{GL}_{1}$ be two groups over $\mathbb{Q}$, where $D$ is a quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$.
It is *well-known* that the automorphic quotient, $Z(\mathbb{A})G(\mathbb{Q})\backslash G(\mathbb{A})$, is not compact for $G = G_{1}$, but compact for $G = G_{2}$. However, it is hard to understand this (at least for me) since two groups $G_{1}(\mathbb{A})$ and $G_{2}(\mathbb{A})$ are *almost* same in the sense that they match up for all but finitely many places (i.e. $G_{1}(\mathbb{Q})_{p} \simeq G_{2}(\mathbb{Q}_{p}) \simeq \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Q}_{p})$ for all but finitely many $p$). What makes such differences in compactness? It would be great if someone provides a good reference for the proofs for non-compactness and compactness. Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: Is compactness still holds when $D$ splits at archimedean place, i.e. when $D(\mathbb{R}) \simeq \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Doesn't seem crazy as $GL_2(\Bbb{R})/\Bbb{R}^* GL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ is not compact while $\{ x\in Q(\Bbb{R}), \|x\|^2=1\}$ is compact.

Comment: @reuns I agree with that, but how it translates into the context of adeles?

Comment: It proves that the adelic stuff is not compact for $G=GL_2$. With $G=Q$ for $a\in Q(\Bbb{A})$ then take $b\in Q(\Bbb{Q})$ such that $ab\in Q(\Bbb{Z}_p)$ for all finite prime, then take some $r\in \Bbb{R}^* \subset Z(\Bbb{A})$ such that $\|(abr)_\infty\|^2 = 1$. A sequence of this kind of stuff will have a convergent sequence in the compact group $Q(\Bbb{R})_{unit ball} \prod_p Q(\Bbb{Z}_p) $ (I didn't check all the details tell me if you see a flaw, $c\in Q(\Bbb{Z}_p)$ means both $c$ and $c^{-1}$ have coefficients in $\Bbb{Z}_p$)

Comment: @reuns Thanks, I'll try to check the details. If I understand correctly, for general $G$ (let's say reductive group over $\mathbb{Q}$), does the compactness of automorphic quotients actually comes from compactness at archimedean places? For non-archimedean places, $G(\mathbb{Z}_{p}) \subseteq \mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ is compact, so the only issue comes from archimedean places... right?

Comment: You problaly assume the strong approximation for $G$

Comment: @SeewooLee No, even for GL(2).  You can choose $D$ which is ramified (so $D_v^\times$ is compact mod center) at any finite even set of places $v$, which need not include $\infty$.

Comment: This is certainly in Platonov and Rapinchuk. Have you looked there?

Comment: @Kimball It makes me confused again, and actually that was a point I didn't mentioned in the question. If $D$ does split at non-archimedean place, then is the quotient still compact?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thank you for your recommendation, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, even though (because a division algebra splits locally almost everywhere) the two groups are locally-almost-everywhere the same, one *global* quotient is non-compact, and the other is compact.

Yes, even if the division algebra is split at all archimedean places, if it is non-split at *any* place, then the (global) quotient is compact.

This applies to the $GL_n$ situation, and central division algebras of dimension $n^2$ over global fields. This is proven by "Fujisaki's Lemma" (as it is called in Weil's "Adeles and algebraic groups", which is just a slight non-abelian generalization of the argument that $\mathbb J^1/k^\times$ is compact (e.g., [http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/fujisaki.pdf](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/fujisaki.pdf) for the abelian case).

For other classical groups, such as orthogonal groups, again the quotient is compact if and only if the form is *globally* anisotropic. (I have some notes on this, based on part of Godement's Bourbaki notes on reduction theory: [http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/cptness_aniso_quots.pdf](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/cptness_aniso_quots.pdf))

By Hasse-Minkowski (and more elementary properties of $p$-adic quadratic forms), for quadratic spaces of dimension five or more, anisotropy is possible if and only if the form is anisotropic at at least one archimedean place (since $p$-adic quadratic forms in dimensions five or higher are demonstrably isotropic).

So, yes, for other classical groups, compactness at (at least one) archimedean place/s is necessary for compactness of the quotient. But over number fields with several archimedean places, many local groups can be non-compact... all it takes is a single compact factor.

And, as @AlexYoucis commented, Platonov and Rapinchuk is probably the best, most authoritative, and most encyclopedic source for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! I actually have a follow-up question. As I know, a linear algebraic group $G$ over $k$ is called *anisotropic* iff it has no non-trivial $k$-split torus in it. In case of quaternion algebra, it seems that it is not anisotropic since $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ is in $D_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\times}$. I can understand that the group of (reduced) norm-1 elements in $D_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\times}$ *is* anisotropic (which resembles $\mathbb{J}^{1}$ you mentioned), but $D_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\times}$ seems not. What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, there is some ambiguity in use of "(an)isotropic", depending whether we refer only to semi-simple groups, or possibly allow reductive groups as well. The natural definition of $GL_n$-type groups, with division algebras, etc., produces reductive, not semi-simple groups, while the isometry groups of "forms" produce semi-simple groups. To make a good comparison, either take the projectivized $GL_n$-type group, or the reduced-norm-one subgroup, to talk about the isotropic/anisotropic distinction analogously. :)

Comment: @SeewooLee The correct notion that you want for a reductive gorup, as alluded to by Dr. Garrett, is the folowing. TFAE:
$\text{}$
1) $G^\mathrm{ad}$ contains no split torus,
$\text{}$
2) $G^\mathrm{der}$ contains no split torus,
$\text{}$
3) $G(F)$ contains no non-trivial unipotent elements,
$\text{}$

4) $G$ contains no proper parabolic subgroups,

$\text{}$

5) if $F$ is a $p$-adic local field or $\mathbb{R}$ this is further equivalent to $G(F)$ being compact.

$\text{}$

You could call this 'anisotropic', but probably the more common terminology is 'anisotropic mod center'.